# Perl Hash of Arrays of Arrays

Tags: arrays, perl, hash, multidimensional-array, perl-data-structures

I'm having some variables in my Hash of multidimensional arrays disappear as soon as I leave a for-loop. The variables are printed correctly one-by-one in the loop, but when I print any item outside of the loop, it is always empty except for the first item.

```
for my $y (0..$last_row - 2) {
    my $mlid = $Sheet->Cells($y+2, 1)->{'Value'}; 
    my @a = ();
    $a[0] = $Sheet->Cells($y+2, 3)->{'Value'}; 
    $a[1] = $Sheet->Cells($y+2, 4)->{'Value'}; 
    $a[2] = $Sheet->Cells($y+2, 6)->{'Value'}; 
    $a[3] = $Sheet->Cells($y+2, 7)->{'Value'}; 
    $a[4] = $Sheet->Cells($y+2, 8)->{'Value'}; 
    push @{$longHash{$mlid}}, [ @a ];
    print "Item in Array in Hash: $longHash{$mlid}[1][0]\n"; #this prints nothing

    if (exists $numPeople{$mlid}){
        $numPeople{$mlid}++;
    }else{
        $numPeople{$mlid} = 0;
        $numPeople{$mlid}++;
    }
}

print "Item in Array in Hash: $longHash{7202}[0][0]\n"; #this prints properly
print "Item in Array in Hash: $longHash{7202}[1][0]\n"; #this prints nothing
```

The behavior SHOULD be:

I have a hash. The key for a single mlid gives an array (representing a person).
In each of the array, there should be another array, in which the 0-4 indexes are defined from an Excel file I'm reading.

So, to get the data from the mlid 7202, from the 7th person, and the 4th column in Excel, I should put $longHash{7202}[7][1] (because I mapped the 4th column to the 1th value of the array.)

Comment: You just changed the code, and now `$y` is not an index into the hash.  Can you please comment and say what the behavior should be?  I think all you need to do now is change `$longHash{7202}[0][0]` to `$longHash{7202}[0]`.

Comment: Change `push @{$longHash{$mlid}}, [ @a ];` to `$longHash{$mlid} = [ @a ];` if you are doing `$longHash{7202}[0]` and not `$longHash{7202}[0][0]`.

Comment: But I need the extra information in 3 tiers. MLID, Person, Person stats. There are multiple of each and I can't get rid of one tier.

Comment: OK, just checking.  I have updated my answer.  I think your code should be working now.  If it's not, please try my example and see if it works.  If it does, then maybe there is a different problem.  For example, maybe there is only one person in `$mlid==7202`.  Try adding `use strict; use warnings;`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are overwriting `$longHash{$mlid}` in every iteration of the loop, so in the best case `$longHash{7202}[$x]` will only be defined for one value of `$x`.

Unless you are doing something a lot more complicated than what you show here, I don't think you need to clear `$longHash{$mlid}` at all. Saying

```
$longHash{key}[index] = expression
```

will auto-vivify both `$longHash{key}` and `$longhash{key}[index]` without the need for any pre-initialization.

(  `$longHash{$mlid} = ()` also looks a little strange -- you are assigning an empty list to a scalar variable. I don't think it's any different from saying `$longHash{$mlid}=0`. If you meant to set it to an empty array reference, then you should use `[]` instead of `()`).

Comment: I noticed the overwriting and edited it. The main problem seems to be finding the index to go in that statement. I changed the code to have a push call, but that doesn't work either. I just want the index to be the exact size of the current array I'm adding to.

Answer (score 2):

I see two problems.

1. `$longHash{$mlid} = ()`

You are trying to set a scalar field to a list.  {$mlid}` should be set to a list *ref*, not a list.  The simplest fix is `$longHash{$mlid} = []`, but that won't fix the real issue.

2.
`$longHash{$mlid}[$y] = [ @a ];` in combination with `$longHash{$mlid} = ();`

You are clearing `$longHash{$mlid}` on every pass thru the loop, then trying to assign to a non-zero index.  Maybe what you want here is a hash of hash rather than a hash of list.

**UPDATE**

In your new version, I think

```
push @{$longHash{$mlid}}, [ @a ];
```

should just be

```
$longHash{$mlid} = [ @a ];
```

**UPDATE 2**

I think your code should be working now.

It seems to be equivalent to my simplified example below:

```
my %hash;

my @a;
$a[0] = "Fred";
$a[1] = 31;
$a[2] = "Melbourne";

push @{$hash{7202}}, [ @a ];

$a[0] = "Mary";
$a[1] = 25;
$a[2] = "Sydney";

push @{$hash{7202}}, [ @a ];

print $hash{7202}[0][0] . "\n";
print $hash{7202}[1][0] . "\n";
```

**UPDATE 3**

Please add

```
use warnings;
use strict;
```

to ensure that all the array indexes you think exist do exist.

And try iterating over your data to print it, e.g.

```
for my $mlid (keys %hash) {
    my $recordref = $hash{$mlid};
    my @record = @$recordref;
    for my $i (0..scalar(@record)-1) {
        printf "mlid %s person %d name %s\n", $mlid, $i, $record[$i][0];
    }
}
```

Comment: I removed the "$longHash{$mlid} = ()" line completely, it still doesn't print the second array "$longHash{$mlid}[1]"

Comment: No, I need to have a multidimensional array. One mlid maps to multiple people (each one gets an array because each of those people has multiple values).